# Set value of an object based on combobox selection (xaml / c#, uwp)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, universal

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is take a selected item from a combobox on Page 1 and set the image source on Page 2 based on that selection, but I'm not exactly sure how to make this happen.

On Page 1 I have:

```
 private void pOneColorChoice(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       setPlayerOneColor = PlayerOneColor.SelectedItem; 
    }
```

On Page 2 I'm not sure how to call that selection and then fit it into this to set the image:

```
BitmapImage ImageOne;

        if (PlayerOneColor == Black)
        {
            ImageOne = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/Black.jpg"));
            PlayerOneImage.Source = ImageOne; 
        }
```

I would add other statements for the other color choices. I'm probably way off but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are navigating to the `Page2` you can send it as a parameter

```
private void pOneColorChoice(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       setPlayerOneColor = PlayerOneColor.SelectedItem; 
       Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), setPlayerOneColor);
    }
```

Here in Page 2 Navigation Method you can get your parameter like this

```
var name = e.NavigationParameter as yourType;
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been answered here, you can pass your option as a parameter when you navigate to the page.

I'd recommend taking a look at following an MVVM design pattern for your application though, this way you can access your other page's view model from other pages. [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/) is a great starting point.

Doing it with this method will let your have one view model for your settings page where you choose your option, and then from the other, you'd access that same property which you've changed. I can go into more detail if required :)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've been teaching myself UWP development with very little previous coding knowledge. I've been trying to find a good tutorial series on MVVM and how to implement it. If you have time to go into more detail about how to implement MVVM with Light at a very basic level, I'd greatly appreciate it. Maybe the info on that linked page would be the best place to start.